# Searchform for searching specific categories

Tags: search, categories

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" size="15" />
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Select' ); ?>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

This snippet gives me a searchbox with a selectbox in which I can choose which category I want to search in. That's nice, but **I don't want to show it ALL categories that I have, no, I want to show it specific categories.**

How can I do this? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [search in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) shows there are some parameters you can set to exclude some categories for example :

```
 <?php $args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'show_option_none'   => '',
'orderby'            => 'ID', 
'order'              => 'ASC',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1, 
'child_of'           => 0,
'exclude'            => '',
'echo'               => 1,
'selected'           => 0,
'hierarchical'       => 0, 
'name'               => 'cat',
'id'                 => '',
'class'              => 'postform',
'depth'              => 0,
'tab_index'          => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'hide_if_empty'      => false
); ?>
```